# How do I cut, copy and paste with formatting?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, formatting

I have a WinForms application with a richTextBox. I would like to be able to cut, copy and paste formatted text in my application. Currently, my code consists of:

Cut all:

```
richTextBoxPrintCtrl1.Cut();
```

Cut Selected:

```
Clipboard.SetText(richTextBoxPrintCtrl1.Text);
        richTextBoxPrintCtrl1.Text = "";
```

Copy all:

```
richTextBoxPrintCtrl1.Copy();
```

Copy Selected:

```
Clipboard.SetDataObject(richTextBoxPrintCtrl1.SelectedText);
```

Paste:

```
DataFormats.Format myFormat = DataFormats.GetFormat(DataFormats.Text);
        richTextBoxPrintCtrl1.Paste(myFormat);
```

I would like it so that if I cut/copy text from the richTextBox, it keeps ALL formatting (size, font, colour etc.), and if I paste text to the richTextBox, it also keeps all formatting.

How would this be achieved?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this two function:

**COPY**

```
    private void Copy()
    {
        Clipboard.SetText(richTextBox1.Rtf, TextDataFormat.Rtf);
    }
```

**PASTE**

```
    private void Paste()
    {
        if (Clipboard.ContainsText(TextDataFormat.Rtf))
        {
            richTextBox1.Rtf = Clipboard.GetText(TextDataFormat.Rtf);

        }
    }
```

Comment: Cheers. Do you have any idea how I could get Copy All working? I've tried Clipbiard.SetText(richTextBoxPrintCtrl1.SelectAll.Rtf, TextDataFormat.Rtf);, but that doesn't work.

Comment: @Toby:you must use Clipboard.SetText(richTextBox1.Rtf, TextDataFormat.Rtf); this will get all text with format,i already tried this.it's work fine

Comment: Oh, okay. It's just using richTextBoxPrintCtrl1.Copy(); copied ALL text from the RTB, regardless of whether it was selected or not.

Comment: Sorry, had a derp moment. I figured it out now. Just run the SelectAll code before the copy code. Thanks.

Comment: @Toby:You do not need to perform SelectAll command before sent to clipboard.Clipbiard.SetText will get all text:D

Comment: Alright. Anyways, thanks for your help bud. I have it implemented now and it works fine. I think my application is complete!